# Error Buildout Plone 4.3.11 with python 2.7 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, plone, buildout

Does anyone know how I can fix this error that I get when I do a buildout?
`sudo -u plone_buildout bin/buildout`
this error appeared

```
Develop: '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/src/bika.lims'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Develop: '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/src/baobab.lims'
Develop: '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/src/graphite.theme'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Updating zeoserver.
Installing client1.
/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-30.3.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:184: RuntimeWarning: You have iterated over the result of pkg_resources.parse_version. This is a legacy behavior which is inconsistent with the new version class introduced in setuptools 8.0. In most cases, conversion to a tuple is unnecessary. For comparison of versions, sort the Version instances directly. If you have another use case requiring the tuple, please file a bug with the setuptools project describing that need.
  stacklevel=1,
Develop distribution: graphite.theme 1.2
uses namespace packages but the distribution does not require setuptools.
Download error on http://dist.plone.org: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://download.zope.org/ppix/: hostname 'download.zope.org' doesn't match 'vm06.plyp.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://download.zope.org/distribution/: hostname 'download.zope.org' doesn't match 'vm06.plyp.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://effbot.org/downloads: hostname 'effbot.org' doesn't match either of 'www.github.com', '*.github.com', 'github.com', '*.github.io', 'github.io', '*.githubusercontent.com', 'githubusercontent.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'collective.wtf' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'collective.wtf'.
Couldn't find index page for 'collective.wtf' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing client1.
  Getting distribution for 'collective.wtf'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'collective.wtf'.
```

Answer (score 2):

See here:
https://community.plone.org/t/pypi-deprecation-of-support-for-non-sni-clients-breaks-buildout-for-older-plone-versions

Your log shows you have setuptools 30.3.0.  That is too old.  You need to use a version of setuptools between 36.8.0 and 44.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1- i install setuptools 44.1.1 and zc.buildout 2.13.1

```
baobab20@baobab20-VirtualBox:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster$ pip list

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Package     Version
pip         20.3.4
setuptools  44.1.1
wheel       0.37.0
zc.buildout 2.13.1
```

#### 2- i modify buildout.cfg

```
[versions]
zc.buildout = 2.13.1
setuptools = 44.1.1
Pillow = 3.4.2
Products.PloneHotfix20160830 = 1.3
Products.PloneHotfix20161129 = 1.2
MarkupSafe = 0.23
Products.DocFinderTab = 1.0.5
bobtemplates.plone = 1.0.5
buildout.sanitycheck = 1.0.2
collective.checkdocs = 0.2
collective.recipe.backup = 3.0.0
mr.bob = 0.1.2
pkginfo = 1.4.1
plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller = 4.3.2
requests = 2.12.3
requests-toolbelt = 0.7.0
twine = 1.8.1
zest.pocompile = 1.4
```

#### 3- i try to buildout,this error appeared :

```
baobab20@baobab20-VirtualBox:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster$ sudo -u plone_buildout bin/buildout

Download error on http://download.zope.org/ppix/: hostname 'download.zope.org' doesn't match 'vm06.plyp.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://download.zope.org/distribution/: hostname 'download.zope.org' doesn't match 'vm06.plyp.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://effbot.org/downloads: hostname 'effbot.org' doesn't match either of 'www.github.com', '*.github.com', 'github.com', '*.github.io', 'github.io', '*.githubusercontent.com', 'githubusercontent.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Getting distribution for 'setuptools==44.1.1'.
While:
Installing.
Loading extensions.
Getting distribution for 'setuptools==44.1.1'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'setuptools==44.1.1'.
```

Comment: The fact that in step 3 it tries to download setuptools==44.1.1 tells me that your buildout is still using the old setuptools, which is self-defeating.  It also tells me that the python/pip used in step 1 and step 3 are different.  Do you have an `activate` script in `bin/` or in your python virtual environment?  Do a `which pip` and a `which python`.

Comment: The version in the egg are not the same in the pip list

baobab20@baobab20-VirtualBox:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster$ which pip

/home/baobab20/.local/bin/pip

baobab20@baobab20-VirtualBox:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster$ which python

/usr/bin/python

baobab20@baobab20-VirtualBox:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster$ head bin/buildout 

#!/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.7/bin/python

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-30.3.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py2.7.egg',
  ]

import zc.buildout.buildout

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @webmobile-nailiapps , I was able to have it working (same problem with 4.3.18).

1. I checked (by using the Plone `pip`) the version of `setuptools` and `zc.buildout` were already the suggested ones:

```
zinstance# ../Python-2.7/bin/pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.3.4
setuptools 44.1.1
wheel      0.37.1
```

2. I updted `buildout.cfg`:

```
--- buildout.cfg.orig   2022-11-25 06:56:34.771083040 +0000
+++ buildout.cfg    2022-11-25 06:41:35.435275637 +0000
@@ -231,8 +231,10 @@
 # config files.
 #
 [versions]
-zc.buildout = 2.5.3
-setuptools = 27.3.0
+zc.buildout = 2.13.1
+setuptools = 44.1.1
 Pillow = 5.1.0

 buildout.sanitycheck = 1.0.2
```

3. Since there is a chicken and egg problem, I had to manually download `setuptools`:

```
zinstance# ../Python-2.7/bin/pip download -d ../buildout-cache/downloads/dist/ setuptools==44.1.1 --no-binary ":all:"
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting setuptools==44.1.1
  Downloading setuptools-44.1.1.zip (858 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 858 kB 7.8 MB/s
Saved /mnt/opt/Plone-4.3.18/buildout-cache/downloads/dist/setuptools-44.1.1.zip
Successfully downloaded setuptools
```

4. Invalidate the existing egg:

```
zinstance# mv -vi ../buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-27.3.0-py2.7.egg ../buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-27.3.0-py2.7.egg.no
```

At this point it can find the required packages without the SNI/Download error.